# using css pagestyle is there a way to columnize the result?

Tags: html, css, printing, printing-web-page

I'm trying to make a webpage that will display normally in a browser, but when printed will print using 2 columns per page. Is there a way to get the text to flow from the left to right column, and have it paginate correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS3 there is a Multi-Column module which is designed just for this.

Unfortunately, being CSS3 the `column-count` property is currently only supported in Firefox 3.6 `-moz-column-count`, Safari 4 and Chrome `-webkit-column-count`, as you can see in this overview:

http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-columns-browser-support

But there is a javascript library that will add this functionality to most older browsers! You can find this script, as well as a really good explanation of the multi-column module in this 2005 article on A List Apart:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/

Comment: Apparently my google-fu massively failed on that one if it missed alistapart.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it will mainly depend on how you have structured your HTML code.

But this is a good example to hopefully get you started: http://dev.joeblade.com/2009/08/using-css-columns-in-print-layouts/. Unfortunately, this works only in Firefox.

You may need to create a seperate print page with the two column structure.